# Remove first zero from billing phone number after registration

Tags: php, woocommerce, preg-replace

When registrants sign up, they often add a leading `0`. I would like this to be removed after registration. I have tried the below, but it's not working (cq it's not updating the proposed outcome). Anyone a thought?

So: `'billing_phone', '0123456789'` should result in `'billing_phone', '123456789'`

```
add_action('user_register', 'removezero', 10, 1);
function removezero( $user_id ) {
    if (isset($_POST['billing_phone'])) {
       update_user_meta( $uder_id, 'billing_phone', $_POST['billing_phone'] = preg_replace('/^0/', '', $_POST['billing_phone']));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? The regex matches one single leading `0`.

Comment: You have `$uder_id` after `update_user_meta(`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in your update-function, try:

```
function removezero( $user_id ) {
    if (isset($_POST['billing_phone'])) {
       update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $_POST['billing_phone'] = preg_replace('/^0/', '', $_POST['billing_phone']));
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see the typo. Am I blind?

Comment: first param in the update_user_meta, your code says "uder" instead of "user" :)

Comment: Yes that answers; I am blind. Thanks for borrowing your eyes!